# Anti-Symmetric Complex Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups, symmetric-functions

Let $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ be a complex polynomial. Show the following two conditions on $f$ are equivalent: i) for any transpositions $\tau$ we have $\tau.f=-f$ and ii) for any $\sigma \in S_n$ we have $\sigma f=f$ when $\sigma$ is even and $\sigma .f=-f$ when $\sigma$ is odd. Such a polynomial is said to be anti-symmetric. Show that $\Delta (x_1,...x_n)$ is anti symmetric, where $\Delta (x_1,...x_n)$=$\Pi_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$.

---

I should also note that $\tau.f=f(x_{\tau(1)},...x_{\tau(n)})$. I'm unsure how to define the function so I can start the proof. Furthermore for the last part the difference function is given as $(x_n-x_{n-1})(x_n-x_{n-2})....(x_2-x_1)$. I'm trying to find a relationship between the number of times a "swap" will occur upon a transposition and furthermore conclude that it's antisymmetric. I understand why  $\Delta (x_1,...x_n)^2$ is symmetric though.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

The transpositions $s_i = (i \; i+1) \in S_n$, $(1 \le i < n)$ generate and satisfy the Coxeter relations
$$
\begin{align}
s_i^2 &= 1 \\
s_i s_j &= s_j s_i \quad &\text{if } |i - j| > 1 \\
s_i s_j s_i &= s_j s_i s_j \quad &\text{if } |i - j| = 1
\end{align}
$$
In other words, any permutation $\tau \in S_n$ can be written (not uniquely) as a product of these standard generators.
$$
\tau = s_{i_1} s_{i_2} \cdots s_{i_r}
$$
The [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithm implements this.

The *length* $\ell(\tau)$ of a permutation $\tau$ is the minimum length of all words that yield that permutation.

(Try to verify for yourself that $\ell(\tau) = 3$ for $\tau = (1 \; 3) \in S_3$.)

Now, the *sign* $\operatorname{sgn}(\tau) = (-1)^{\ell(\tau)}$, and a permutation is called even (resp., odd) if the length of the permutation is even (resp., odd).

---

To see that the [Vandermonde polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_polynomial) $\Delta(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is alternating (anti-symmetric), observe that a single transposition, say $(i \; j)$ has the following effect on the factors $(x_t - x_u)$:
$$
\begin{align}
(x_i - x_u) &\longleftrightarrow (x_j - x_u) & \text{if } t \in \{i, j\} \text{ and } u \notin \{i, j\} \\
(x_t - x_i) &\longleftrightarrow (x_t - x_j) & \text{if } t \notin \{i, j\} \text{ and } u \in \{i, j\} \\
(x_i - x_j) &\longleftrightarrow (x_j - x_i) & \text{if } \{s, t\} = \{i, j\}
\end{align}
$$
All other factors are fixed.  In the first two cases, two factors in the polynomial algebra are interchanged, so the product is unchanged.  The last case involves replacing a factor by its opposite, which switches the sign of $\Delta$.